# Calculating the distributional Jacobian determinant

Tags: integration, derivatives, determinant

I need help calculating an integral. I have a function $u: \mathbb{R}^n\supset B_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $u(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$.
I need to calculate the following integral (i.e. the distributional Jacobian determinant):

$$\int_{B_1(0)} (u\cdot \textrm{adj} Du)\cdot D\phi$$

for every $\phi\in C^\infty_c(B_1(0)).$

I know that this should be $\delta_0 \mathcal{L}(B_1(0))$, where $\delta$ is the usual Dirac delta and $\mathcal{L}(B_1(0))$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I tried to calculate it in two dimensions and got
$$u\cdot \textrm{adj} Du = \frac{x_1^2 x_2^2}{||x||}\left(\frac{x_1}{||x||^3-x_1^2||x||},\frac{x_2}{||x||^3-x_2^2||x||}\right).$$

That is where I got stuck. Do you have any tipps?

Thanks and merry Christmas in advance!